# stuck with dalekjs installation

Tags: npm, phantomjs, npm-install, dalekjs

Trying to install dalekjs on Win7 64bit EE. npm version 2.15.8. Ran the command prompt as Administrator.

Created the file package.json under C:\Users\ZW85

```
{
  "name": "myCssTardis",
  "description": "Is awesome",
  "version": "0.0.2"
}
```

Ran npm install dalek-cli -g

> C:\Users\ZW85>npm install dalek-cli -g
>   C:\Users\ZW85\AppData\Roaming\npm\dalek ->
>   C:\Users\ZW85\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod e_modules\dalek-cli\bin\cmd.js
>   dalek-cli@0.0.5
>   C:\Users\ZW85\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dalek-cli └──
>   optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)

Ran npm install dalekjs --save-dev

> C:\Users\ZW85>npm install dalekjs --save-dev 
>   npm WARN package.json
>   myCssTardis@0.0.2 No repository field. npm WARN package.json
>   myCssTardis@0.0.2 No README data npm WARN package.json
>   myCssTardis@0.0.2 No license field. npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.1:
>   lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0. npm
>   WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or
>   higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue npm WARN deprecated
>   CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as 'css-select' npm WARN
>   engine node-pngjs@0.0.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current:
>   {"node":"4.4.7","npm":"2.15.8"}) npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.0.9:
>   this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date
>   with respect to npm npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is
>   now available as 'css-what' /
>   phantomjs@1.9.12 install C:\Users\ZW85\node_modules\dalekjs\node_modules\dalek-browser-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs
>   node install.js
>
> Download already available at
>   C:\Users\ZW85\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip
>   Extracting zip contents Removing
>   C:\Users\ZW85\node_modules\dalekjs\node_modules\dalek-browser-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom
>   Copying extracted folder
>   C:\Users\ZW85\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip-extract-1471504147493\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows
>   -> C:\Users\ZW85\node_modules\dalekjs\node_modules\dalek-browser-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom
>
> \

It's not proceeding from here. Tried multiple times.

Also tried running a test program

> C:\Users\ZW85>dalek test/*.js
>
> > Running tests
> >     ERROR: dalek-driver-phantomjs: Binary not found: null

Installed phantomjs separately and tried, still same error. Would be great if anyone can point out what I'm missing here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the same issue as [DalekJS v0.0.5 installation hung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40151771/dalekjs-v0-0-5-installation-hung)

Long story short, make sure your devDependencies look like this:

`"devDependencies": {
    "dalekjs": "0.0.9",
    "dalek-browser-phantomjs":"https://github.com/wrumsby/dalek-browser-phantomjs/tarball/b0b6c011eec55ea7da987461f6e1c79a6ab4bf6e"
  }`

Referencing this specific version of dalek-browser-phantomjs should fix the hang.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the path for phantomjs got too long on Windows.

Go to:

```
   C:\Users\[YOURNAME]\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip\
```

and remove the exmaples folder. re-run installation.. worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I am on Ubutnu 16 and this worked for me,
change the package.json file to

```
{  
    "name": "myCssTardis",  
    "description": "myTest description",  
    "devDependencies": {  
        "dalekjs": "0.0.9",  
        "dalek-browser-phantomjs":"https://github.com/wrumsby/dalek-browser-phantomjs/tarball/b0b6c011eec55ea7da987461f6e1c79a6ab4bf6e"  
    }  
}
```

then you won't face the

> ERROR: dalek-driver-phantomjs: Binary not found: null