# DalekJS v0.0.5 installation hung

Tags: node.js, dalekjs

I am using Windows 10 x64 version 1607 - build 14393.222.
Issue also reproduced on Windows 7 x64 SP1.
DalekJS version:
C:\Users\Administrator>dalek -v
DalekJS CLI Tools Version: 0.0.5
Brought to you with love by: Sebastian Golasch (@asciidisco) 2013

NodeJS installation was successful - node-v6.8.0-x64.msi
"npm install dalek-cli -g" command was successful
"npm install dalekjs --save-dev" - this command was hung for over 8 hours.

See snapshot attached.

[DalekJS installation hung at PhantomJS install step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRVtM.jpg)

Tried with Node.js v6.9.0 as well as v4.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this as well. I don't know exactly what the issue is but it is linked to the `dalek-browser-phantomjs` package. There is a pull request to fix it that hasn't been integrated yet.

To fix you problem, make sure you are referencing this version of dalek-browser-phantomjs:

`"dalek-browser-phantomjs":"https://github.com/wrumsby/dalek-browser-phantomjs/tarball/b0b6c011eec55ea7da987461f6e1c79a6ab4bf6e"`

Your package.json should look like this:

`"devDependencies": {
    "dalekjs": "0.0.9",
    "dalek-browser-phantomjs":"https://github.com/wrumsby/dalek-browser-phantomjs/tarball/b0b6c011eec55ea7da987461f6e1c79a6ab4bf6e"
  }`

Try `npm install` again and it should work.